# android: do I need different density copies for each resource?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why provide multiple drawables for various densities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214843/why-provide-multiple-drawables-for-various-densities)

Lets say I have a splash screen which is scaled in a way to always fit the full screen.
Does it make sense to package 4 different density version of the same image?
Why not let android handle the down-scaling?

Another example would be button icons. Why not packaging only `xhdpi` and let android do the work? Is it a memory issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it make sense to package 4 different density version of the same image? Why not let android handle the downscaling?

That depends on whether you like the results of the downscaling. If you do, use it. If you don't, supply other artwork for the densities that need it.

> Is it a memory issue?

Partly, it is a speed issue, as downsampling takes CPU time (and, hence, a bit more battery).

Partly, it is a quality issue, as the downsampling that Android does means you are not in final control over what the image looks like. You might be happy with the downsampling of your images; other developers may not be happy with the downsampling of their images.

For example, the Nexus 7 is a `-tvdpi` device. However, *Google* doesn't bother with `-tvdpi` images -- they let Android downsample the `-xhdpi` images. The images seem perfectly reasonable to me, and apparently  to Google as well. OTOH, Google does ship `-mdpi` images, not only for `-mdpi` devices, but to serve as the basis for downsampling for `-ldpi`.

Comment: But is it a memory issue? What I mean is: does android downscale the image, and read the downscaled version into RAM before drawing it to the screen, or does android downscale the image, and keep the original hi-res version in RAM?

Comment: @stoefin: I have no idea. You are welcome to run some tests and use MAT to try to determine this.